# install IE 9 on windows 7 VM

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-7

I need to install IE 9 on a Windows 7 VM for testing but I can't find Internet Explorer 9 download. The links to Microsoft to download IE 9 are pointing to IE 11. I saw some other links in Microsoft social and those are gone too. I even tried installed IE 7 and then patch it up and remove IE 11 from Programs and Features like some suggested and it reverted to IE 8. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

You need to look for the redistributable package.  Here's a direct link to IE9 32 bit for windows 7:
[HERE](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/3/B/C3BF2EF4-E764-430C-BDCE-479F2142FC81/IE9-Windows7-x86-enu.exe)

Comment: Hi Dimitri, thank you. The link downloads IE9-Window7-x86-enu.exe and it won't install on x64. When I run the installer there is a message: "Wrong version of Internet Explorer installer, This version of setup doesn't support your Windows system type (32-bit/64bit)". Do you have  a link for x64?

Comment: Try this: [link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/1/6/C167B427-722E-4665-9A40-A37BC5222B0A/IE9-Windows7-x64-enu.exe)

Comment: Dimitri, thanks again. After several Windows update cycle, IE 9 surprisingly showed up. I still tried your X64 download on another Windows 7 instance and it seems like it would work. I got all the way to install but I cancelled because I didn't want to clobber my test IE 8 VM. I'm sure someone else will benefit from your post. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with the same issue and found that you can download virtual box images from Microsoft: "Test Microsoft Edge and versions of IE8 through IE11 using free virtual machines you download and manage locally" (also supports other vm software like Vagrent, VM, VmWare etc.)

[Link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/)

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, after several automatic Windows update cycles later, an update with IE 9 appeared along with IE 10 (unchecked IE 10). After the update, I got IE 9.